# How to show more than 5 tabbar Item in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to show 6 tabbar item but its not allow me to do that.its only shows 4 tabbar . After 4 its show  ... More section . How can I show 6 tabbar item at the same time .

[image: tabbar items]

Comment: Create custom tab bar - HStack with buttons.

Comment: You need to create a custom TabBar as per Asperi's suggestion. Just make sure you *really* want to do that. It may not  be a good UX design - that's why the 5-item limit exists in the native TabBar.

Comment: Thank you for the answers im gonna try all of them.